# Query element in array in google datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

How can I retrieve and update an element inside an array stored in datastore?

I have an entity called 2019-06-26. This entity has an array called houses. I want to update houses[3] in datastore, how do I do that? I find it impossible to find the right query.

Comment: Do you mean with a GQL query? If not, could you share what programming language you are using to access the data in Datastore?

Comment: @pessolato I am using Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

With Google’s Node.js client library you can retrieve the entity with the array property and then change the values of the elements you want.

The sample code below retrieves an entity of kind “Team” by its name, set the value for the player at index 2 as a new object and saves the entity with the new values:

```
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

async function quickStart() {
    const projectId = '[PROJECT_ID]';

    const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
    });

    const kind = 'Team';
    const name = 'T01';

    const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);
    const [entity] = await datastore.get(taskKey);

    entity.players[2] = {name: ‘new_player’}; 

    await datastore.save(entity);
}
quickStart().catch(console.error);
```

You can check Google’s [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity) documentation and the [Google Datastore Client official npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore#using-the-client-library) for more information about how to work with entities.

---